# What was written in the note?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-sorcerers-apprentice

In movie [The Sorcerer's Apprentice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sorcerer%27s_Apprentice_%282010_film%29), what was written by young Becky on the note behind which young Dave/David ran and went inside Balthazar Blake's shop of antique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the timeline, in the movie, for everything relating to the note.

- 5:22, David writes the note, passes it to Becky
- 5:35, Audience sees note:

[image: note]

- 5:49, Becky checks something
- 5:54, Becky sets note on base of lamp post
- 5:57, David goes to pick up note, but it blows away and David chases it
- 6:56, Note blows into Arcana Cabana
- 1:30:38 to 1:30:52, David asks Becky about note:

  - David: Hey, Becky. You remember that letter I wrote when we were ten years old, friend or girlfriend? I never saw what you checked. So, in case I die tonight, could you please tell me?
  - Becky: Don't die and I'll tell you.
- 1:41:50 to 1:42:02, Becky gives her response:

  - David: You did it!
  - Becky: I know, and I'm still alive.
  - David: Surprisingly, so am I.
  - Becky: I know. ... Oh, the note. Right, friend or girlfriend.
  - David: Ahh, I don't care.
  - they kiss
  - Becky: Girlfriend. Definitely girlfriend.